# Как узнать путь к SDK и NDK на Mac?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

Как посмотреть в какой директории находятся `SDK` и `NDK` на Mac? Куда они обычно устанавливаются?

Comment: если студия видит sdk и ndk, то в проекте можно открыть файл `local.properties` и там найти пути.

Comment: @andreich А где находится файл local.properties?

Comment: в любом созданном проекте

Comment: О, отлично спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в терминале, то:

SDK  `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android`

NDK  `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android-ndk`

Если в Finder, то `Программы` -> `правой кнопкой мыши на Android Studio` -> `Показать содержимое пакета` -> `Contents/plugins/` -> тут лежат папки `android` и `android-ndk`

UPD: исходники SDK - `/Users/Имя юзера/Library/Android/sdk`